# Получение  данных  из IntentService

Tags: android

Доброго  времени  суток. Есть  интент сервис  запускается  из  активити. Как после  обработки  в  сервисе  дать  знать  вызвавшему  активити  о  том  что  обработка  закончена???

Comment: послать интент в ответ? а внутрь вложить дополнительные данные, что бы активити могла понять, что именно завершилось.

Comment: а  послать  то  как? startActivity(intent); Но  тут  вроде  как  перезапуск  активности  получится  или  я  не  прав?

Comment: [`ResultReceiver`][1] же, и не надо ничего изобретать.

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static final int RESULT_FINISH = 1;

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service.class);
intent.putExtra("receiver", new ResultReceiver(new Handler()){
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_FINISH ){
             Toast.makeText(this, "Service finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
});
startService(intent);
```

В сервисе:

```
ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");

Bundle data = new Bundle();
receiver.send(RESULT_FINISH, data);
```